# preg_replace proper regex for repeating character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

OK I'm stuck again, this time it's a problem with the regex... Was searching google, was searching SO, but there wasn't a post that made me happy... So to make a long story short:

- §text = Database entry string -> could be everything
- $text gets parsed and the regex should replace everything between 2 * with:

  [bla].$matchedtext.[blub]

So I've tried to find the right regex for that and that's what I came up with:

```
$text= preg_replace('~(/\*([^\"]*?)\*/)~', "$1<b>$2</b>", $text);
```

And the 2 * per match should disappear as well :/...

Obviously it doesn't work, elsewhise I wouldn't post :D -> Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably do it:

```
preg_replace('/\*([^"*]*)\*/', '<b>\1</b>', $text);
```

A few comments on your earlier regular expression:

```
[^\"]*?
```

The non-greedy `*` is not necessary; when you're looking at a negative character set, simply add the '*' inside the character set. Also, the double quote doesn't need escaping.

```
[^"*]*
```

You only need memory groups for things you wish to remember; in your case, you don't want to know that you matched a beginning and ending asterisk. So you can do your whole matching with just one memory group.

Comment: Thanks for all the fish :D - just not used to regex - thanks for the explaination!